# Differentiating an "initial value problem"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, initial-value-problems

I have the following ODE

$$y' = 2 - \sin(xy), \qquad 1 \le x \le 3$$

with initial condition $y(1)=-\frac 12$. I have to prove that $|y''(x)| \le 40$ over the domain $[1,3]$.

I thought perhaps just do partial differentiation on y' and then draw it on a graph using the x domain and show its always under 40, but that doesn't seem to work... any help? If it helps, the question is in the context of an Euler question. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Following your idea of differentiating, note that

$$y'' = -\cos(xy) (xy' + y) \implies |y''| \le |x| |y'| + |y|.$$

Now $|x| \le 3$ and $|y'| \le 3$ as well (why?), so it remains to check how large $y$ can get. Since $y(1) = -1/2$ and $|y'| \le 3$, one can quickly show that $|y| \le 6.5$ for $x$ in this range.

Put it all together and you get an upper bound which is quite a bit better than $40$.

Comment: The first line is just the triangle inequality, together with $|\cos(\cdot)| \le 1$. Integrate $y'$ to see why $|y| \le 6.5$.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating the expression yields

$$y'' = -\cos(xy)\left[y+xy'\right]= -\cos(xy)\left[y+x(2-\sin(xy))\right].$$

Using the modulus and the triangular inequality:

$$\implies |y''| \leq |y+x(2-\sin(xy))| \leq |y|+|x||2-\sin(xy)|\leq |y|+3|x|\leq |y|+9.$$

The last thing that remains is finding a bound on $|y|$ in order to do this we notice that $y'>0$. Hence, the values of $y$ are rising all from $x=1$ to $x=3$. The maximal growth rate is $3$ which implies $y'=2-\sin(xy)\leq 3 \implies y(x)\leq 3(x-1)-1/2 \implies |y|\leq 5.5$.

Comment: You say |y|<=6, and the other poster says 6.5. How come?

Comment: This was a mistake on my side edited my answer. $3(x-1)\leq 6$ subtracting $1/2$ gives $5.5$.

Comment: Yes, they are but both estimates are correct. But I think my estimate is tighter.